# How to do Feedback form in IOS?

Tags: ios, radio-button, feedback

I want to put a feedback form in a view in my IOS application.

[image]

There will be 2-3 smiley images. Initially they will be in grey color. When you tap one of them, it will be colored, and the rest stays grey. They will work like radio buttons in HTML.

And there will be 5 questions.

So, what is the best way to handle this feedback form in a native IOS application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best and most simple way would be to do it with an embedded html page. This is great if you already have such a page for the web version.

Another way would be a custom made form in a xib, with custom buttons, but in order for you to actually receive that feedback, you would need to somehow send the data trough a scripted page (php, asp or whatever you like).

I've done similar things and I used the second suggestion I gave you but in my case it was different, because that form had to be presented over an existent view with animation and so on. What I would recommend you is the first one, with the web page.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will use WebView to display the form. Thank you so much.

Comment: With pleasure! Good luck with the app

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the xib to create the view with the question text and buttons for answer options. The buttons can have the smiley images as background image.
Then you can change the image for the smiley on button click for the button state selected. and may be have another button to confirm answer and move to next question that is refresh view with new question text.
Hope this helps.